# How to enable button after all textboxes are not empty in c# winforms?

Tags: c#, winforms, button, textbox

How can I make button property set to enabled=true after all my textboxes are not empty?
I'm learning programming and my apps are simple.

I know how to enable this property when one of my textboxes have text but this is not the case.

Use case is that user need to put data in both textboxes and after that will be able to click btn.
How in most simple way can I validate all form and then enable button?

There are just 2 tb:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/clR0c.png

Comment: As an option, you can handle [`Validating`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.validating?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=net-5.0) event of all the `TextBox` controls using a single event handler and check if none of them are empty, then enable the `Button`.

Comment: @RezaAghaei how can I do this? This is not working.

private void generateHashBtn_Validating(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
        {
            if (loginTextBox.Text != String.Empty && passTextBox.Text != String.Empty)
            {
                generateHashBtn.Enabled = true;
            }
        }

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a `TextBox_TextChanged` event and subscribe to all text boxes.

```
private void TextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int notEmptyTextBoxCount = 0;
    int textBoxCount = 0;
    foreach (var item in Controls)
    {
        if (item is TextBox txtb)
        {
            textBoxCount++;
            if (txtb.Text != String.Empty)
                notEmptyTextBoxCount++;
        }
    }
    if (textBoxCount == notEmptyTextBoxCount)
        button.Enabled = true;
    else
        button.Enabled = false;
}
```

Comment: `button.Enabled = !this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>().Where(x => string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.Text)).Any();`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys for all feedback.

I have managed to do this this way:

```
private void ValidateTextBoxes()
    {
        if (loginTextBox.Text.Length != 0 && passTextBox.Text.Length != 0)
        {
            generateHashBtn.Enabled = true;
        }
        else
        {
            generateHashBtn.Enabled = false;
        }
    }

    private void TextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ValidateTextBoxes();
    }

    private void TextBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ValidateTextBoxes();
    }
```

Comment: If someone writes in box1, then writes in box2, the button gets enabled.  If they erase what's in box1 or box2, the button will stay enabled.

Comment: Thx for noticing this @LarsTech.
I've edited my previous post.